# Outlook analyzing my sent e-mails and ...uploading the info to SharePoint?

Tags: outlook, sharepoint

I just noticed this in my Outlook 2010 settings:

> Allow analysis of sent e-mails to identify people you commonly e-mail and subjects you commonly discuss, and upload this information to the default SharePoint Server.

This setting is discussed *briefly* [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-the-information-you-share-through-your-my-site-and-profile-HA010378254.aspx).

Does anyone know what exactly this setting does?  It was checked when I got to it, so I'm *very* curious about this.  I'm wondering where on SharePoint I might find this data.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not as easy as it looks...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384821.aspx

Comment: Stack Exchange answers should generally be more than external links.